# Not able to get results I want From MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This is a sample from my data

[image]

if the first column is of index 0 , I want to get the total sales per store from this file using MapReduce , Store name is at index 2 and revenue is at index 4

This is my Mapper Code

> 

```
public void map(LongWritable key , Text value , Context context)
throws IOException , InterruptedException
{
    String line = value.toString();
    String[] columns = line.split("\t");

    if(columns.length == 6)
    {
        String storeNameString = columns[2];
        Text storeName = new Text(storeNameString);

        String storeRevenueString = columns[4];
        IntWritable storeRevenue = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(storeRevenueString));
        context.write(storeName, storeRevenue);
    }   
}
```

This is My Reducer Code

> 

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException , InterruptedException {

    Text storeName = key;
    int storeSales = 0;

    while(values.iterator().hasNext())
    {
        storeSales += values.iterator().next().get();

    }
    context.write(storeName, new IntWritable(storeSales));
}
```

this is the code that runs the job

```
public class StoreSales extends Configured implements Tool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // this main function will call run method defined above.
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new StoreSales(),args);
    System.exit(res);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JobConf conf = new JobConf();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Job job = new Job(conf , "Sales Per Store");

    job.setMapperClass(StoreSalesMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(StoreSalesReducer.class);
    job.setJarByClass(StoreSales.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    Path input = new Path(args[0]);
    Path output = new Path(args[1]);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf , input);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, output);

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

    return 0;
    }
 }
```

This is a sample of how results should be 
[image]

this is the result I get
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your file tab  delimited "/t" ? check it .Check your map output if its is giving proper <key,value> pair

Comment: at a guess, the `if(columns.length == 6)` condition is evaluating to false, and the mapper defaults to passing the entire record to the reducer. take a few records from the file, and make a test program which splits the string in the same manner as the mapper, and add some print statements to see what's going on. Hopefully this will give you an idea of what your problem is. I would guess that there's an extra tab character in there somewhere (maybe the end of the record), that causes length to be 7 instead of 6 when split.

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong in the logic of map reduce , it should work the problem i see is i think you are checking the wrong result set because you are only using 2 and 4 column in both the mapper and reducer but you are showing 7 column in result set which is not possible.  If there  could be problem in your input file in that condition your mapper code won't write anything locally if " context.write " won't execute and hence nothing would go to reducer , in that case your part-r file would be blank.

Comment: Actually what I don't understand is why results are giving me 7 columns ?

Comment: @NaderHisham It is probably giving you 7 columns because the condition (length == 6) is not true in the mapper, so it defaults to sending its existing key-value pair to the reducer unmodified. Keys supplied to the mapper are essentially just some random number (those showing up in the output's first column). The value sent onward is the entirety of the record (the rest of the columns). From then onwards your reducer jsut parrot's its input from the mapper, as all keys are unique, so there is no overlap. Please check the parsed length of your input data is actually 6. I suspect it is not.

Comment: I suspect that there is a hidden tab or two at the end of your data, that causes the length of the array in the mapper to be 7 or 8. Please look at your data and check whether this is the case. a sample program that just splits the string and outputs the length should be good here, if you can get a small subset of your data for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your logic , i have used your logic and modified bit in driver program using new map reduce api :

Mapper part

import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>{


    public void map(LongWritable key , Text value , Context context)
            throws IOException , InterruptedException
            {
                String line = value.toString();
                String[] columns = line.split("\\t");

                if(columns.length == 6)
                {
                    String storeNameString = columns[2];
                    Text storeName = new Text(storeNameString);

                    String storeRevenueString = columns[4];
                    IntWritable storeRevenue = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(storeRevenueString));
                    context.write(storeName, storeRevenue);
                }   
            }
}

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException , InterruptedException {

        Text storeName = key;
        int storeSales = 0;

        while(values.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            storeSales += values.iterator().next().get();

        }
        context.write(storeName, new IntWritable(storeSales));
    }

}


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // this main function will call run method defined above.

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Job job = new Job(conf , "Sales Per Store");

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);


    }
 }
```

Sample Input file :

2012-01-01      09.00   sanJose clothin 214     amex

2012-01-01      09.00   seattle music   320     master

2012-01-01      09.00   seattle elec    3120    master

2012-01-01      09.00   sanJose perfume 3200    amex

Output File :

cat test123/part-r-00000

sanJose 3414

seattle 3440

Comment: Thanks man , actually this was the problem after using new API for driver it works fine :) .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have located the problem here. when using the line.split method you have improperly escaped the tab character. This is because the `String.split` method interprets its input as a regex. When using regex, the correct way to specify a tab character is `\\t`, while you are using the `\t`. This is due to the fact that the backslash itself must be escaped. Note that you are missing a `\` character.

corrected split condition

```
String[] columns = line.split("\\t");
```

Comment: Yeah I get your point , however the value is split correctly using \t , I replaced my driver that uses old API with a driver that uses the new API and it worked fine without changing Mapper or reducer code , so this was the problem , I used new API for Mapper and Reducer but for running the Job I used the old API